# Yii2 dropDownlist with add option feature

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown

I am working with a form with a select tag for receive mode (email, fax, courier) and I need to make it a little flexible. If the user cannot find the receive mode in the choices he/she will add the receive mode. Can anybody offer some help if that would be possible? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 0):

Have the receive mode in a seperate table with relationship.

After that display add button in the form. When user selects the button, display modal with receive mode create form which should be saved via ajax. After successfull creation of new receive mode, close the modal and then refresh the receive mode dropdown box.

Comment: Yes. This is the way you can do @Norris.

Comment: @Norris if you need any more explanation revert back

Comment: How can I determine of the validation did not take effect? For example the user did not put anything in the textbox or the user put something already exisitng?

Comment: That modal form will be different and you could take care of the validation is easy only. In my view, i'll just return json encoded _form.php for creation of new mode. if there is any error the _form.php will be returned with error. So i dont have to work too much